# Поиск слова в текстовых файлах

Tags: java, поиск

Делаю небольшую програму для работы с текстом. Хочу реализовать поиск введённого пользователем слова во всех текстовых файлах в каталоге. Как это можно сделать? Нашёл несколько вариантов, которые ищут слова в одном конкретном файле, а как это можно сделать во всех файлах каталога? Есть какие-то примеры или исходники, где это реализовано?

**Вот поиск в одном файле, который у меня есть.**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Searcher {
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    File file = new File("resources\\Block-Tileentity List.txt");
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
  try {
      while(scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] cols = line.split(" ");
    if (cols[1].equals("Слово для поиска")) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }  
      }
  } finally {     
      scanner.close();
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Что вызывает трудности? Вы уже знаете, как найти слово в одном файле, и следовательно осталось только получить *все* файлы каталога (а на этот вопрос уже дано очень много ответов)

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов, вызывает трудности их объеденение. Я могу отдельно вставить код, который ищет слово в одном файле и могу отдельно вставить код для того, чтобы получить путь ко всем файлам, но у меня неполучается их объединить.

Comment: покажите, как выглядит функция поиска в одном файле.

Comment: @RomanKonoval, прикрепил её к вопросу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        final var word = "word";
        try (final var files =
                     Files.find(
                             Paths.get("/path"),
                             Integer.MAX_VALUE,
                             (p, basicFileAttributes) ->
                                     findExtension(p.getFileName().toString()).stream()
                                             .anyMatch(s -> s.equals("txt")))) {
            files.forEach(p -> {
                final var lines = getLines(p);
                IntStream.range(0, lines.size())
                        .filter(i -> Arrays.asList(lines.get(i).split(" ")).contains(word))
                        .forEach(i -> System.out.println("File: [" + p.getFileName() + "], line number: [" + (i + 1) + "], line: [" + lines.get(i)+ "]."));
            });
        }
    }

    public static Optional<String> findExtension(String fileName) {
        return Optional.of(fileName.lastIndexOf('.'))
                .filter(i -> i >= 0)
                .map(i -> fileName.substring(i + 1));
    }

    public static List<String> getLines(Path p) {
        try (final var lines = Files.lines(p)) {
            return lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unexpected error occurred.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: А каким способом можно получить название файла и строку, где было найдено? Именно в вашем варианте

Comment: @Luzz добавил полный путь к файлу и строку в которой были найдены совпадения

Comment: спасибо, вы меня выручили

Comment: пишу довольно поздно. Но всё таки, каким способом можно тут можно вывести номер строки, в которой было совпадение. Понял, что надо использовать .getlinenumber() в p.getFileName(), но что-то у меня не выходит. Можете ещё раз помочь?

Comment: @Luzz добавил номер строки

Comment: ещё раз спасибо